# apache poi: remove and create a comment for the same cell - Multiple cell comments in one cell are not allowed

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, comments, cell

I use in my java application the apache poi library version 4.1.1.
I have a method to set a cell comment that is called in various places in my application.

```
protected void setCellComment(final SXSSFWorkbook workbook, final SXSSFSheet sheet, final Cell cell, 
            final String authorText, final String commentText, final int offsetX, final int offsetY) {  
        
        if (cell.getCellComment() != null) {
            cell.setCellComment(null);
            cell.removeCellComment();
        }
        if (cell.getCellComment() == null) {         
            CreationHelper factory = workbook.getCreationHelper();
            final String commonString = authorText + commentText;
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor(100, 100, 100, 100, cell.getColumnIndex(), cell.getRowIndex(), offsetX, offsetY);
            SXSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();  
            Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
            RichTextString commentRichTextString = factory.createRichTextString(commonString);
            final Font fontAuthor = workbook.createFont();           
            fontAuthor.setBold(true);
            commentRichTextString.applyFont(0, authorText.length(), fontAuthor);
            comment.setAuthor(authorText);
            comment.setString(commentRichTextString);
            cell.setCellComment(comment);
        }
    }
```

This method works very well. But sometimes the cell has a comment already. Then I want to delete the existing comment with

```
cell.removeCellComment();
```

for create a comment with other text and other size (offsetX, offsetY).
This code removeCellComment() is called. But when I create a new comment for the same cell I get the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple cell comments in one cell are not allowed, cell: AG13
```

What can I do to remove/create my comment?
Thanks for your hints, Ann

Comment: could you try latest POI version? - 5.2.2 - there are changes that might help

Comment: @PJFanning For a test I used version 5.2.2 with the same result: Multiple cell comments in one cell are not allowed.

Comment: Have you tried using XSSFWorkbook instead of SXSSFWorkbook? - SXSSF has much lower support than XSSF version does.

Comment: `cell.setCellComment(null)` is not necessary if you intend to call `cell. removeCellComment()`

Comment: You should probably change this code - `SXSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch(); `. Call `sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();` first and check if it is null - if non-null, use that instance of creating a new one

Answer (score 1):

This is a disadvantage of `SXSSF`.

`SXSSFCell.removeCellComment` of current `apache poi 5.2.2` does not really remove the comment from the sheet's `CommentsTable` and from the sheet's `VMLDrawing` as `XSSFCell.removeCellComment` does. It only removes a [Property](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_2/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFCell.java?view=markup#l987). See [SXSSFCell.removeCellComment](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_2/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFCell.java?view=markup#l618). That's why the error coming from `org.apache.poi.xssf.model.CommentsTable.createNewComment`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple cell comments in one cell are not allowed, cell: ...
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.CommentsTable.createNewComment(CommentsTable.java:252)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing.createCellComment(XSSFDrawing.java:387)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFDrawing.createCellComment(SXSSFDrawing.java:53)
...
```

because the comment is not really removed after `SXSSFCell.removeCellComment`.

But why not simply creating a new comment only if not one already exists for the cell? Else only changing the author and the text. That should work for each package, `HSSF`, `XSSF` and `SXSSF`.

Complete example to test:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;

class CreateExcelWithComments {
    
 static void createCellComment(Cell cell, String authorText, Font boldFont, String commentText, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
  // create the text content
  CreationHelper creationHelper = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
  String commentString = authorText + "\n" + commentText;
  RichTextString richTextString = creationHelper.createRichTextString(commentString);
  richTextString.applyFont(0, authorText.length(), boldFont);
  // try to get the cell comment
  Comment comment = cell.getCellComment();
  if (comment == null) { // create a new comment
   // create the anchor
   ClientAnchor anchor = creationHelper.createClientAnchor();
   anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
   anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex() + offsetX);
   anchor.setRow1(cell.getRow().getRowNum());
   anchor.setRow2(cell.getRow().getRowNum() + offsetY);
   // create the comment and set it to the cell
   Drawing drawing = cell.getSheet().createDrawingPatriarch();
   comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
   cell.setCellComment(comment);
  }
  // apply author and text
  comment.setAuthor(authorText);
  comment.setString(richTextString);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xls";
  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xlsx";
  Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xlsx";
  
  Font boldFont = workbook.createFont();           
  boldFont.setBold(true);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row; 

  row = sheet.createRow(3);
  Cell cellF4 = row.createCell(5);
  cellF4.setCellValue("F4");
  sheet.setColumnWidth(cellF4.getColumnIndex(), 10 * 256);   
  createCellComment(cellF4, "Axel Richter", boldFont, "Cell comment for F4", 2, 4);

  row = sheet.createRow(1);
  Cell cellB2 = row.createCell(1);
  cellB2.setCellValue("B2");
  sheet.setColumnWidth(cellB2.getColumnIndex(), 10 * 256);   
  createCellComment(cellB2, "Axel Richter", boldFont, "Cell comment for B2", 2, 4);

  createCellComment(cellB2, "Axel Richter", boldFont, "New Cell comment for B2", 2, 4);
  
  createCellComment(cellF4, "Axel Richter", boldFont, "New Cell comment for F4", 2, 4);

  try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
   workbook.write(out);
  }

  workbook.close();
  if (workbook instanceof SXSSFWorkbook) ((SXSSFWorkbook)workbook).dispose();
 }
}
```

Works for me using `apache poi 5.2.2` in `HSSF`, `XSSF`, as well as `SXSSF`.

---

Of course the above is not able to change the anchors of the comments too. Because the anchors are in the `VMLDrawing` of the sheet and `SXSSFSheet` has no access to it's `VMLDrawing`, this is only possible using the `VMLDrawing` got from the `XSSFSheet`. And since even the `XSSFVMLDrawing` not provides to change the anchors directly but only to remove them and set new, the reference to the old `VMLDrawing` needs to be changed in sheet's `CommentsTable` too. So we need an explicit `removeCellComment(SXSSFCell cell)` only for `SXSSFCell` . That all only is possible using a ugly reflection approach. See next code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;

class CreateExcelWithComments {
    
 static void removeCellComment(SXSSFCell cell) throws Exception {
  SXSSFSheet sxssfSheet = cell.getSheet();   
  java.lang.reflect.Field _sh = SXSSFSheet.class.getDeclaredField("_sh");
  _sh.setAccessible(true);      
  XSSFSheet xssfSheet = (XSSFSheet) _sh.get(sxssfSheet);
  org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellAddress ref = cell.getAddress();
  
  java.lang.reflect.Method getCommentsTable = XSSFSheet.class.getDeclaredMethod("getCommentsTable", boolean.class);
  getCommentsTable.setAccessible(true);      
  org.apache.poi.xssf.model.CommentsTable commentsTable = (org.apache.poi.xssf.model.CommentsTable)getCommentsTable.invoke(xssfSheet, false);
  java.lang.reflect.Method removeComment = org.apache.poi.xssf.model.CommentsTable.class.getDeclaredMethod("removeComment", org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellAddress.class);
  removeComment.setAccessible(true);      
  removeComment.invoke(commentsTable, ref);
      
  java.lang.reflect.Method getVMLDrawing = XSSFSheet.class.getDeclaredMethod("getVMLDrawing", boolean.class);
  getVMLDrawing.setAccessible(true);      
  XSSFVMLDrawing vmlDrawing = (XSSFVMLDrawing)getVMLDrawing.invoke(xssfSheet, false);
  java.lang.reflect.Method removeCommentShape = XSSFVMLDrawing.class.getDeclaredMethod("removeCommentShape", int.class, int.class);
  removeCommentShape.setAccessible(true);      
  removeCommentShape.invoke(vmlDrawing, cell.getRowIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex());    
 }
    
 static void createCellComment(Cell cell, String authorText, Font boldFont, String commentText, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
  // create the text content
  CreationHelper creationHelper = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
  String commentString = authorText + "\n" + commentText;
  RichTextString richTextString = creationHelper.createRichTextString(commentString);
  richTextString.applyFont(0, authorText.length(), boldFont);
  // try to get the cell comment
  Comment comment = cell.getCellComment();
  // if there is a comment already, then remove it
  if (comment != null) {
   cell.removeCellComment();
   if (cell instanceof SXSSFCell) {
    try {
     removeCellComment((SXSSFCell)cell);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();   
    }
   }
  }
  // create the anchor
  ClientAnchor anchor = creationHelper.createClientAnchor();
  anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
  anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex() + offsetX);
  anchor.setRow1(cell.getRow().getRowNum());
  anchor.setRow2(cell.getRow().getRowNum() + offsetY);
  // create the comment in drawing
  Drawing drawing = cell.getSheet().createDrawingPatriarch(); // this tries to get first in apache poi 5.2.2
  comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
  // set author and text
  comment.setAuthor(authorText);
  comment.setString(richTextString);
  // apply comment to cell
  cell.setCellComment(comment);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xls";
  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xlsx";
  Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xlsx";
  
  Font boldFont = workbook.createFont();           
  boldFont.setBold(true);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row; 

  row = sheet.createRow(3);
  Cell cellF4 = row.createCell(5);
  cellF4.setCellValue("F4");
  sheet.setColumnWidth(cellF4.getColumnIndex(), 10 * 256);   
  createCellComment(cellF4, "Axel Richter", boldFont, "Cell comment for F4", 2, 2);

  row = sheet.createRow(1);
  Cell cellB2 = row.createCell(1);
  cellB2.setCellValue("B2");
  sheet.setColumnWidth(cellB2.getColumnIndex(), 10 * 256);   
  createCellComment(cellB2, "Axel Richter", boldFont, "Cell comment for B2", 2, 2);

  createCellComment(cellB2, "Axel Richter New", boldFont, "New Cell comment for B2", 2, 4);
  
  createCellComment(cellF4, "Axel Richter New", boldFont, "New Cell comment for F4", 2, 4);

  try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
   workbook.write(out);
  }

  workbook.close();
  if (workbook instanceof SXSSFWorkbook) ((SXSSFWorkbook)workbook).dispose();
 }
}
```

This works for me using `apache poi 5.2.2`. But it is not well tested and so a working draft at first.

Comment: Thank you Axel. A redesign would be very costly. I collect all the information for the comment and then I write this only once.